# Maximum size of application memory space on 32 (x86)? 2 Gb or 1 Gb?

Tags: x86, virtual-memory

What amount of memory is available (theoretically) to application on 32 bit system? Different OSes? 2 or 1 Gb?

thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the OS.

32-bit Windows by default allocates 2GB to the application and 2GB to the kernel, so theoretically your application could allocate up to 2GB. You can change this allocation on some versions of windows by using the 4GT boot flags. Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613473%28VS.85%29.aspx) MSDN article for more information.

64-bit Windows has much more, something like 8TB.

I think Linux in general has 3GB of user space, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: And Windows 32bit apps running on a 64bit instance get 4GB. But allow 32but Windows apps not flagged "large address aware" are always limited to 2GB.

Comment: so you say that on windows it is not less then 2 gb?

Comment: 32bit Windows will give at least 2GB virtual address space to application.

Comment: Although it does not mean that you can actually allocate 2GB on a real system. That depends on a lot of other factors.

Answer (score 0):

All of the memory is available to the application. There may be limits on how much address space the application can use, and thus how much memory it can map at one time. But typically, the application can use every single byte of physical memory if it wishes to.

Comment: I really ment what part of virtual address space can app use.

Comment: This is the problem with the word "memory". It can mean physical memory, virtual memory, and various things in-between. This confusions leads people to think that, for example, there's no point in putting more than 2GB of RAM in a 32-bit OS that runs "one big application". That is, of course, not true. If nothing else, the application still benefits (and gets to use) the disk cache, which is in memory. (And a 32-bit app on a 64-bit OS gets to use the whole disk cache -- potentially all of physical memory.)